# 2 dimensional array simple understanding

Tags: c

I have some old code of mine which i dont understand why i did some thing .
I have a pointer which is `int_16t *q`, of 1024 ints . now i am trying to copy it with :

```
       buffersRing[ringNum][0]=inNumberFrames;
       memcpy(buffersRing[ringNum]+1, q, inNumberFrames * sizeof *q);
```

when first place in array is some int variable, and all other place after that are q.

But, why i havnt done that(and whats the difference ) :

```
    buffersRing[ringNum][0]=inNumberFrames;
    memcpy(buffersRing[ringNum][1], q, inNumberFrames * sizeof *q);
```

Is it trying to put all q ints into the first place in array ? or is it the same?

Comment: Yes the code is valid and works great. it does something very interesting, get the samples from a microphone, and do some dsp on it. by the way , the question is a basic C, to understand the +1 in the array, and what does it means .

Comment: You could use `&buffersRing[ringNum][1]` though.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No,

```
buffersRing[ringNum]+1 // refers to a pointer to an array element
```

is not the same as

```
buffersRing[ringNum][1] // refers to the actual array element
```

The first one is the one you want.