# What does sizeof without () do?

Tags: c, sizeof

The author of [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18898410/2-dimensional-array-simple-understanding) just made fun on me when I asked him what 
`sizeof * q` does...
He told me that's a really basic C question and I should check it out.
But as I looked around on SO and haven't seen some one asking before, I'll do it now by my self:

What does `sizeof` in C do when it is used without parentheses and/or type?

Comment: I could be wrong but I believe sizeof(expr) is the same as sizeof expr. No doubt someone will correct me if I am wrong!

Comment: Relevant: [Why is sizeof considered as an operator?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1393582/why-is-sizeof-considered-as-an-operator/1393592)

Answer (score 25, accepted):

So if we look at the grammar for `sizeof` in the [C99 draft standard](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg14/www/docs/n1256.pdf) section `6.5.3` *Unary operators* paragraph *1* it is as follows:

```
sizeof unary-expression
sizeof ( type-name )
```

There is a difference you can not use a *type-name* without parenthesizes and section `6.5.3.4` *The sizeof operator* paragraph *2* says(*emphasis mine*):

> The sizeof operator yields the size (in bytes) of its operand, which may be an
>   expression **or the parenthesized name of a type**.[...]

For completeness sake you may wonder if we can use `sizeof` with an expression if we have parenthesizes and the answer is yes since a *unary-expression* can itself contain parenthesizes. The easiest way to see this would be to look section `A.2.1` *Expressions* from the draft standard and work through the grammar like so:

```
unary-expression -> postfix-expression -> primary-expression -> ( expression )
```

Answer (score 23):

`sizeof` is an operator, not a function, so you don't need the `()` if the operand is an expression (but you normally use them). `sizeof * q == sizeof(*q)`. Note that if the operand is a type, you need to use the `()`, so `sizeof(int)` (see for example http://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/C_Programming/Reference_Tables)

```
sizeof      sizeof operator for expressions sizeof 123
sizeof()    sizeof operator for types       sizeof (int)
```

Now even the [wiki](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sizeof) is full of informations about C... The world is changing fast :-)

> The sizeof operator is used to determine the amount of space a designated datatype would occupy in memory. To use sizeof, the keyword "sizeof" is followed by a type name or an expression (which may be merely a variable name). If a type name is used, it must always be enclosed in parentheses, whereas expressions can be specified with or without parentheses.

Answer (score 9):

`sizeof` is an *operator*, specifically a unary operator like unary `&` or `++`.  It takes either a unary expression or a type name surrounded by parens as its operand.

The syntax is

```
  sizeof unary-expression 
  sizeof ( type-name )
```

So, given a declaration like

```
int *q;
```

the expressions `sizeof *q` and `sizeof (int)` are equivalent, as are `sizeof q` and `sizeof (int *)`.

Answer (score 4):

The same thing as sizeof with parantheses. It'a a right side unary operator, so it treats its right size as operand.
As far as I know paranthesis are obligatory when using sizeof with basic data types.

When you have a variable `int a` you can check its size both ways, parantheses are not mandatory: `sizeof a`, `sizeof (a)` will work the same.
But when checking size of int itself only `sizeof (int)` will work.

Answer (score 3):

The same thing it does with parens - it returns the size of whatever you pass it, in this case the size of whatever is pointed to by `q`.

It's somewhat less clear, though, especially when we get involved with complex calls to `malloc` and `sizeof`, so I consider it to be best practice to always use the parens.