# Confusing results from 'sizeof' operator

Tags: c, gcc, declaration, sizeof

I recently tried this code and was a little confused. See the following declarations:

```
 static   st;
 auto     au;
 register reg;
 volatile vl;
 const    cn;
```

They all are allocating memory of 4 bytes (on 32 bit GCC). But when i try to print (using `printf` function) their sizes, they are not working and giving errors.

```
  sizeof(const)      // worked and printed 4
  sizeof(volatile)   // worked and printed 4

  sizeof(auto)       // error: expected expression before ‘auto’
  sizeof(static)     // error: expected expression before ‘static’
  sizeof(register)   // error: expected expression before ‘register’
```

My doubt is `auto, static, register` *keywords* also allocating memory of 4 bytes(on 32 bit arch).

But why these are giving errors unlike `const` and `volatile`?

Comment: Size of keyword? Why do you even expect a result back?

Comment: The type is defaulted to int. It's the same thing that happens when you declare `unsigned a;`

Comment: Title says "C", and tags are C and C++. Does C have `auto`? *Pick a language* instead of shotgunning.

Comment: @texasbruce i'm expecting result as 4 bytes. For example, register keyword stores in CPU registers. It can directly give `cpu register size` as the result

Comment: Yes, C has `auto`. It means `auto`matic storage.

Comment: from classical C (or even B) comes the infamous "everything not type declared is an int" feature that you are seeing here, so all your stuff are ints.

Comment: You are probably aware, but it is worth pointing out that you can of course still do `sizeof au`, `sizeof st` and `sizeof reg`, and get the same value as `sizeof int` in each case.

Comment: @MagnusHoff: yes i know.  but why they are not working when we directly giving?

Comment: @PlasmaHH:  That rule does not exist in C++.  See footnote [92] in the C++11 Standard:  "There is no special provision for a decl-specifier-seq that lacks a type-specifier or that has a type-specifier that only specifies
cv-qualifiers. The “implicit int” rule of C is no longer supported."

Comment: Simply compile with a C standard compiler and the code will not compile (C99 or C11).

Comment: @Lundin  How to know which c compiler I'm using?

Comment: @SGG You claim to be using GCC so I would assume that's the one? Simply compile with correct compiler settings for standard C: `gcc -std=c99 -pedantic-errors -Wall`. Or if you have an brand new version of GCC, I suppose it has -std=c11.

Comment: @JohnDibling: The OP is about C code compiled with a C compiler, clearly being about C, and not at all about C++

Comment: @PlasmaHH:  Is `auto` part of C now?

Comment: @Lundin it seems in practice that even though *C99* removed implicit int, many compilers will allow it with a warning. Sadly it seems even with `-pedantic-errors`.

Comment: @ShafikYaghmour Not a single line of the OP's code passes `gcc -std=c99 -pedantic-errors -Wall`. I don't know how you managed to compile it without errors.

Comment: @Lundin I just tried again and `clang` does indeed still allow it with only warning although `gcc` does not, I thought both did yesterday [see clang working here](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/60e2adcd62b61373).

Comment: @ShafikYaghmour Then it would seem that Clang doesn't follow the standard. If that is the case, I would uninstall it and replace with GCC.

Comment: @JohnDibling: C always had an `auto` keyword, yes.

Comment: @Lundin that is a bit extreme, although it does look like a bug, let me see what it takes to report it.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

In C prior to the 1999 standard, an unspecified type would default to `int` in many contexts.

C99 dropped that rule, and omitting the type is now illegal (strictly speaking, it's a *constraint violation*, requiring a diagnostic -- which could be a non-fatal warning). In any case, omitting the `int` type has always been a bad idea. (It goes back to C's predecessor languages BCPL and B, which where largely typeless.)

```
static   st;
auto     au;
register reg;
volatile vl;
const    cn;
```

These declarations are all legal in C90 (and all the variables are of type `int`), but they're invalid in C99.

```
sizeof(const)      
sizeof(volatile)
```

Somewhat to my surprise, these are actually legal in C90 (but not in C99). `const` or `volatile` by itself is a type name, equivalent to `const int` and `volatile int`, respectively. Syntactically, `const` and `volatile` are *type qualifiers*.

```
sizeof(auto)
sizeof(static)
sizeof(register)
```

The distinction is that this:

```
const int x = 42;
```

defines `x` to be an object of type `const int`, while this:

```
static int x = 42;
```

defines `x` to be a *static* object of type `int` (`static` isn't part of the type).

These are all syntax errors, because `auto`, `static`, and `register` are not type names. Those keywords are *storage-class specifiers*.

This explains why the first two `sizeof` expressions seem to work, and the others do not. But that's not particularly useful to know, because if you specify the type `int` (which you always should), it doesn't matter that `sizeof(const)` happens to be valid (in C90, not in C99).

The bottom line is that you should always specify the type in any declaration. And though you can legally write `sizeof (const int)`, it's guaranteed to be the same as `sizeof (int)`, so there's not much point in using `const` in that context.

Answer (score 10):

Prior to *C99* if you did not specify a *type* then *int* would be implied which is what is happening in your code. It looks like in practice even in *C99* mode `gcc` and `clang` will just produce warnings. This is a case where compiler warnings are your friend, I tried this in `clang -Wall`:

```
printf( "%zu\n", sizeof(const) ) ;
```

and it warns me:

```
warning: type specifier missing, defaults to 'int' [-Wimplicit-int]
```

All the declarations here:

```
static   st;
auto     au;
register reg;
volatile vl;
const    cn;
```

also have an implied *int type*.

We can see that *C99* [removed the implicit int](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/C99) assumption:

> a declaration that lacks a type specifier no longer has int implicitly assumed. The C standards committee decided that it was of more value for compilers to diagnose inadvertent omission of the type specifier than to silently process legacy code that relied on implicit int. In practice, compilers are likely to display a warning, then assume int and continue translating the program.

If we look at the [draft C99 standard](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg14/www/docs/n1256.pdf) *Forward* section paragraph *5* includes the following:

> [...]Major changes from the previous edition include:

and has the following bullet:

> — remove implicit int

**Update**

So why does `sizeof` not like *storage class specifiers* like *static* and *auto* but is okay with *type qualifiers* like *const* and *volatile*, the behavior seems inconsistent with how the declarations work and should the *implicit int* assumption still work?

Well if we look at the grammar for `sizeof` in the *draft standard* section `6.5.3` it is as follows:

```
sizeof unary-expression
sizeof ( type-name )
```

So neither a *type qualifier* nor a *storage class specifiers* is an *expression* but a *type qualifier* is a *type-name*, if we look at section `6.7.6` the grammar for *type-name* is as follows:

```
type-name:
  specifier-qualifier-list abstract-declaratoropt
```

and `6.7.2.1` gives us the grammar for *specifier-qualifier-list* which is as follows:

```
specifier-qualifier-list:
  type-specifier specifier-qualifier-listopt
  type-qualifier specifier-qualifier-listopt      <- Bingo allows type qualifier
```

So we can see that `sizeof` just does not accept *storage class specifiers* even if the *type* is explicitly specified to *int*, so even the following is an error:

```
printf( "%zu\n", sizeof(static int) ) ;
```

and `clang` tells us:

```
error: expected expression
   printf( "%zu\n", sizeof(static int) ) ;
                           ^
```

and we can further see that *type names* won't work with `sizeof` without `()`:

```
printf( "%zu\n", sizeof  int ) ;
```

produces an error:

```
error: expected expression
```

but *unary expressions* work with `()` as I explained previously [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/18898832/1708801).

Comment: No. I'm not geting any warning and errors. GCC compiler. and it's giving result as 4.

Comment: Please enable `-Wall`. GCC will warn you.

Comment: @SGG I just tried using `-Wall` and it gives me a similar warning.

Comment: The answer is clear and concise ... Just try and you will see by yourself :)

Comment: @SGG for *C* you will get a warning and for *C++* you will receive an error.

Comment: ok. and why we use `-wall`. what it will do? Is it compiles without gcc extensions?

Comment: @SGG You don't get an error but the warning is quite explicit. It tells you how it interprets the lack of specifier, i.e. `defaults to 'int'`, and acts accordingly.

Answer (score 1):

The `auto`, `static`, `register` keywords don't identify any type, but *modify the way a variable of that type* is stored or accessed.

So:

```
sizeof(auto)       // error: expected expression before ‘auto’
sizeof(static)     // error: expected expression before ‘static’
sizeof(register)   // error: expected expression before ‘register’
```

make no sense, because you're not requesting the size of any type. Instead:

```
sizeof(const)      // worked and printed 4
sizeof(volatile)   // worked and printed 4
```

These identify types: `volatile int` and `const int`. So you can use `sizeof` on them.

Notice that when you're declaring your variables, the compiler is assuming `int` as their underlying type. Most compilers (GCC, Clang) will emit warnings if you're relying on this behaviour.

Answer (score 1):

`extern`, `static`, `auto`, `register` are called **storage-class-specifier**, while `const`, `restrict`, `volatile` are called **type-qualifier**.

For type-qualifiers, when used without **type-specifier**, `int` is implicitly specified in C89.

> C89 §3.5.2 Type specifiers
>
> `int`, `signed`, `signed int`, or no type specifiers

These types listed are the same with each other. While **no type specifiers** has been removed in C99 in the same section:

> C99 §6.7.2 Type specifiers
>
> `int`, `signed`, or `signed int`

Answer (score 0):

Your declarations are all invalid, so the results are largely irrelevant.

The size of a variable/object depends on its data type, such as `int` or `float`. The keywords you tried modify the way the compiler handles the variable/object, but they do not alter or dictate its type (therefore they have no bearing on its size).

For your `const` and `volatile` declarations, the compiler was likely defaulting to type `int` (but that's not behaviour you should ever rely on).

Comment: It's not c++ . In c auto means automatic storage.

Comment: My mistake. Thanks Arpit. I'll take that out.