# C: sizeof(), sizeof () and sizeof

Tags: c, sizeof

I have read a post on `C` before here on SO. I have forgotten what it was about, but definitely was not about what I would like to ask here - `sizeof`.

It was argued between 2 answerers in the comment section. It was a heated debate between the two but an explanation was never explicitly uttered.

I have tried to find it for two days, but I have not been able to locate it, hence my question here. And Googling didn't generate any result regarding this.

**Focus:** `sizeof()` or `sizeof ()` or just `sizeof`

So there are basically 2 types of these people regarding this:

***First group:***

A scholar who swears by the name of Ritchie and never will drive a car because he tries to register his license plate with:

`sizeof ()` with a space between `sizeof` and `()` and the government (in some countries this - `()` - is allowed in license plates) won’t allow the empty space between numbers/letters.

***Second group:***

Every once in a while a decorated C veteran with a tie-dyed shirt who would reply you like so when asked: „I really don’t know man, what’s the difference? I don’t even know what the deal is. I don't even remember.. Those Ivy Lea…. `sizeof()`, `sizeof ()` or just `sizeof`, me no worry, man. “

So, should `sizeof` be written with a space between `sizeof` and its `()` or even without the `()` or really it doesn’t matter?

I welcome explanations from C experts and scholars. Those who don’t quite fit into the aforementioned types - the self-taught `C` Bobs and Marys - with „C99 and Ritchie“ tattooed on his/her arm are also welcomed.

It doesn’t hurt me either ways but I am just curious whether or not if it is a „standard“ to put a space between `sizeof` and `()` or even one without `()`.

Or are they really *all the same* - would be interesting to me.

Comment: There is a lot of irrelevant info in your question. Please edit it and strip it down to just the core question.

Comment: @RemyLebeau It's fun to read, though :-) But, yes, it could be more to the point...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Quick review of the C spec for examples:

1. `()` after `sizeof` is not used when not needed.

   ```
   sizeof *dp
   ```
2. A space is used between `sizeof` and `()` otherwise (as in with a type name).

   ```
   sizeof (struct ss)
   ```

Obvious the 3 styles by the OP are all allowed and the spec does not mandate any 1 of the 3 (aside from `()` with a type name).

IMHO, I concur with @drew_w comment about `sizeof()`.

Comment: "a space is used between sizeof and () otherwise...".. because?

Comment: @Unheilig §6.5.3 specifies 2 uses of the `sizeof` operator:  `sizeof` _unary-expression_ and `sizeof (` _type-name_ `)`.  Why the C spec examples used the style `sizeof[space](struct ss)` instead of `sizeof[nospace](struct ss)` is something I could only at best conjecture: committee compromise.

Comment: You can 0 or more spaces

Comment: @David Heffernan Certainly one can use 0+ spaces between `sizeof` and `()`.  The C spec is not obliging code use a given number of spaces.  Still the spec does have a uniform style in its _examples_ that is 1  space and I thought that was worth noting to this post.

Answer (score 7):

All yield the same result and which you use is entirely down to preference.

Note that you must use parens if you are supplying a type name. More detail on that can be found here: [What does sizeof without () do?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18898736/what-does-sizeof-without-do)

Comment: Personally I always use the parens just after the "sizeof" with no space. This follows most function calling conventions and thinking of "sizeof" as a function isn't harmful (IMHO)

Answer (score 5):

No difference in `sizeof()` and `sizeof ()`. But there is a little difference in `sizeof` and `sizeof ()`. The standard says about it:

### 6.5.3 Unary operators:

```
sizeof unary-expression
sizeof ( type-name )
```

If the operand is type name, then `()` is needed. Otherwise, for unary-expressions you can use it without `()`.