# Using sizeof a struct in its constructor

Tags: c++, struct, constructor, sizeof

I am trying to initialize a `struct` in its constructor but I run into a compiler error on the last line when I am initializing the member `header.length`. Is its size known at the time?

This is the compiler error and the `structure`:

```
In constructor ‘stDescriptor::stDescriptor()’:
error: expected primary-expression before ‘)’ token


struct stDescriptor {
    usb_functionfs_descs_head   header;
    stDescriptorBody fs_descs;
    stDescriptorBody hs_descs;

    stDescriptor(){
        header.fs_count = 3;
        header.magic = cpu_to_le32(FUNCTIONFS_DESCRIPTORS_MAGIC);
        header.hs_count = 3;
            header.length = cpu_to_le32(sizeof stDescriptor);
         }
};
```

Answer (score 4):

You need

```
header.length = cpu_to_le32(sizeof(stDescriptor));
```

because `stDescriptor` is a type name, not an expression.

#### 5.3.3 Sizeof [expr.sizeof]

> **1** The `sizeof` operator yields the number of bytes in the object representation of its operand. The operand is
> either an expression, which is an unevaluated operand (Clause 5), or a parenthesized type-id. [...]

Comment: Question aside: is sizeof(expression) a sizeof expression ?

Comment: @DieterLücking if I understand you correctly, yes, this [is a C question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18898736/what-does-sizeof-without-do/18898832#18898832) but the logic is the same.