# When should we use sizeof with and without parentheses

Tags: c++, c

```
typedef struct rem{
    int  addr;
    char addrbuf[32];
} foo;
```

Both of these codes return the same results

```
foo addr;
printf("size is: %d\n",sizeof addr);
printf("size is: %d\n",sizeof (foo));
```

size is: 36

size is: 36

But when should we use `sizeof` with and without parentheses?

Comment: Related [What does sizeof without () do?](http://stackoverflow.com/q/18898736/1708801)

Answer (score 49, accepted):

When using `sizeof` with a *type,* you need parentheses around the type. When using it with an *expression,* you don't. But you can of course include them in this case as well, and you don't have to worry about operator precedence in such case. With uncommon operators such as this one, fewer people would be sure of the precedence, so clarity certainly helps.

So I'd say it's preferable to use them always.

Comment: Nit: depending on the expression, you may still need parentheses even then. `sizeof a + b` doesn't mean `sizeof (a + b)`. (I know that's what you meant too.)

Comment: @hvd That's why I mentioned (and now elaborated on) operator precedence.

Comment: @hvd: There's no parentheses around that expression.  There are parentheses inside the expression, of course, controlling parsing.

Comment: A worse situation would be `char x[10]; sizeof(x + 1)` will be very different from `sizeof x + 1`.

Comment: Yeah, I didn't think you thought otherwise. :) @BenVoigt In `sizeof (a + b)`, there are parentheses around the expression `a + b`.

Comment: @hvd: But the expression `a + b` is not the operand of `sizeof`.  The expression `(a + b)` is.  There are no parentheses around the operand.

Comment: @BenVoigt Let me rephrase, then. If you have the expression `a + b`, and want to use it as an operand of `sizeof`, you cannot do so directly, you need to first put parentheses around it. And you're right that that makes `(a + b)` the operand of `sizeof`.

Comment: @hvd: It's also important to note that parentheses may be required around `sizeof operand`.  Consider `char a; int x = sizeof(a)["abcdef"];`  What is `x` ?  Would you know whether that is equivalent to `sizeof (a["abcdef"])` or `(sizeof a)["abcdef"]` ?  Very confusing to people who assume the `()` are part of the sizeof syntax.

Comment: @BenVoigt I would, because a common use of `sizeof` is `sizeof array / sizeof array[0]`, so I'm well aware that `[0]` is part of the operand of `sizeof`. :) To disambiguate, when `(sizeof a)["abcdef"]` is meant, I would strongly prefer `"abcdef"[sizeof a]`, without a need for parentheses around `sizeof a`.

Comment: @hvd: Of course.  But it comes as a surprise to people who think that `sizeof (expression)` takes care of operator precedence concerns.  Of course, for `(sizeof a)` and `[sizeof a]` alike, there's clearly no value to putting parentheses in the operand, doing so just adds line noise.

Comment: @hvd: But if "Expressions with unary operators group right-to-left" and `sizeof`, unary `+`, and cast are all the same precedence, why is `sizeof (int)+5` equivalent to `(sizeof (int))+5` and not `sizeof ((int)+5)` ?

Comment: @BenVoigt; In `sizeof (int)+5`, `+` will be treated as binary `+` and `(int)` will go with `sizeof`. In `sizeof ((int)+5)`, no evaluation of operand takes place and it will return the size of type.

Comment: @BenVoigt What haccks said, but also, "Expressions with unary operators group right-to-left" isn't something I've said, and I'm not sure what you're quoting from. The C grammar is clear that `sizeof`'s expression operand must be a *unary-expression*, not a *cast-expression*.

Comment: @hvd: The quoted text is straight from the Standard.  But actually, you're right, casts have their own grammar production not mixed with *unary-expression*.  So the precedence table on Wikipedia is wrong.

Comment: @BenVoigt Ah, sorry, the question is tagged both C and C++, and I was looking at the C standard, which does not contain those same words.

Comment: It's because `sizeof`has priority over `+`: https://en.cppreference.com/w/c/language/operator_precedence  @iharob

Answer (score 15):

[expr.sizeof]/1:

> The operand is either an *expression*, which is an unevaluated operand
>   (Clause 5), or a **parenthesized *type-id***.

Thus the parentheses are required for types only. If you prefer to use parentheses for clarity and consistency (as I do) you can always use them though, as parentheses around an *expression* form another *expression*.
The operator precedence of `sizeof` is not very well known and could cause irritations.

Also, for the `sizeof...` operator, you always have to use parentheses (another reason for consistency).

Comment: cause irritations ... like what ?

Comment: @Meninx What is the value of `sizeof 1*2`? Is it intuitive?

Comment: @Columbo; From which standard you have quoted it?

Comment: @haccks N3337 (C++11), but the quote should have remained the same since C++98

Comment: @Columbo: the value is machine-dependent ! but I can say that it is the same as sizeof(int) * 2

Comment: @Meninx Exactly. Who expects `sizeof 1*2` to be twice the size of an `int`? It's not quite obvious, IMO.

Comment: Okay get it now @Columbo ! Thanks for your explanation ! :)