# The result of "sizeof" depends on the location of the brackets. Why?

Tags: c, expression, sizeof, operator-precedence, unary-operator

There is a code:

```
 float x=-8.92;
 int y=5;
 printf("%u\n", sizeof x+y);
 printf("%u\n", sizeof (x+y));
```

Conclusion:

```
9
4
```

Why is this happening(result 9)? After all, these are simple unary operations.

Comment: `sizeof x+y = sizeof(x)+y = 4+5 =9`

Comment: `sizeof x == 4` -> `y == 5` -> `4 + 5 == 9`

Comment: `sizeof` does not need brackets. Brackets are necessary only for data type e.g. `sizeof (int)`.

Comment: Please see this post [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28075100/when-should-we-use-sizeof-with-and-without-parentheses) about when to use the parentheses.

Comment: @i486 *`sizeof` does not need brackets. Brackets are necessary only for data type e.g. `sizeof (int)`*  Which means you should always use them.  Nevermind they make bugs like those demonstrated by this program impossible.

Comment: regarding; `float x=-8.92;`   The literal: `-8.92` is declaring a `double` value which is then being converted to a `float` value.  To declare a `float` value use: `-8.92f`  Notice the trailing `f`

Comment: regarding: `printf("%u\n", sizeof x+y);
 printf("%u\n", sizeof (x+y));`  The `sizeof` returns a `size_t`, which is a `unsigned long int`   A `u` is not a valid output format specifier for a `size_t`  Suggest using: `%zu`

Comment: @AndrewHenle Brackets cannot help to someone who is writing `sizeof (x+y)`.

Comment: @i486 The meaning of `sizeof (x+y)` is clear.  What help is needed there?  If that's not what the programmer meant, that's not a problem with the language syntax and more than replacing `x + y` with `x / y` would be.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This expression

```
sizeof x+y
```

is equivalent to the expression

```
( sizeof x ) + y
```

So as `sizeof x`  is equal to `sizeof( float )` that is `4` then the result of the original expression is equal to `9`.

The operator `sizeof` is an unary operator and its operand is in turn an unary expression.  That is the operator in particularly is defined like

```
sizeof unary-expression
```

`x + y` is an additive expression while the variable `x` as a primary expression is in turn an unary expression. Thus the operator is applied to the variable x.

On the other hand, the expression `( x + y )` is a primary expression and due to the usual arithmetic conversions has the type `float`. So in this case that is when the expression is written like `sizeof( x + Y )` the operator `sizeof` is again applied to a primary (unary) expression and is equivalent to `sizeof( float )`.

Pay attention to that instead of the conversion specifier `%u` you shall use the conversion specifier `%zu` in the calls of `printf`. The type of the both expressions `sizeof x + y` and `sizeof( x + y )` is `size_t` that is an implementation defined type that usually is an alias for the type `unsigned long`. For the type `size_t` there is defined the conversion specifier `zu` that you shall use. Otherwise a call of `printf` with an incorrect conversion specifier can invoke undefined behavior.

Comment: Thank you for the detailed answer. Can you suggest why you should use "%zu" instead of "%u"?

Comment: @Thepersonwiththequestion See my appended answer.

Answer (score 4):

The `sizeof` operator has higher precedence than the binary addition operator `+`.  So this:

```
sizeof x+y
```

Parses as:

```
(sizeof x)+y
```

So in the first expression you're getting the size of a `float` which is 4 on your system and adding the value 5 to that, resulting in 9.  For the second expression, the subexpression `x+y` has type `float` because of the *usual arithmetic conversions*, so the result is 4 which is what's printed.

Comment: Thanks. I really forgot about the priority of unary operations.

Answer (score 2):

`sizeof x+y` is the same as `(sizeof x) + y`, i.e. `sizeof` has **higher precedence** than `+`.

Your compiler should have warned you about the mismatch between the `printf()` format string (`%u`) and the argument (`size_t`, `int` or other) - if you're using GCC, you should add `-Wall -Wextra` to your compilation command.

Comment: I will definitely study "- Wall -Wextra". Thanks for the tip .

Comment: The actual type of the argument is size_t in both calls, the correct format specifier is `%zu`.

Comment: @zwol, `int` + `size_t` is not necessarily `size_t`.  But yes, I did get `x` and `y` the wrong way around - now fixed.

Comment: @TobySpeight I guess technically you _could_ have `size_t` be smaller than `int` (minimum maximum for `size_t` is 65536, same as both `unsigned short` and `unsigned int`) but that seems like a really weird ABI to me. Do you know of a real ABI that does that?

Comment: Oh yes, it does sound very unlikely, I'll grant that.  No, I don't know of such systems (but I tend to work with mainstream Unix workstations, so I'm not likely to).   Also, I struggle to memorise the common type of signed and unsigned values for arithmetic.  Anyway, thanks for pointing out that I'd forgotten which variable was a `float`.

Answer (score 0):

> *The result of “sizeof” depends on the location of the brackets. Why?*

Because "brackets" override operator precedences.