# Is the "(int)" in "sizeof (int)" a typecast operator or some special case parameter? [C]

Tags: c, casting, sizeof

I always assumed the C expression `sizeof (int)` worked like a function, with whatever is inside the parentheses being passed like a parameter. As `int` (or any other type specifier) is actually a keyword and not an object that can be passed, I assumed it was just some sort of special case hard coded into compilers.

But I recently discovered that if I use `sizeof` on a variable, I can omit the parentheses (`sizeof var`) and it'll compile and run fine. Since `sizeof` is actually an operator itself and not a function (and operators don't need parentheses), and types specifiers are the only things that need parentheses, now I'm wondering if they're really type specifiers or if they're actually type cast operators somehow being used by `sizeof` to find sizes for the corresponding types.

Comment: see [What does sizeof without () do?](http://stackoverflow.com/q/18898736/1708801)

Comment: Also relevant: [Why is sizeof considered as an operator?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1393582/why-is-sizeof-considered-as-an-operator)

Comment: Wow, thanks. I clearly was using the wrong phrases in my searches.

Comment: That is why duplicates can be useful, they may help others find the right question due to different wording.

Comment: Instead of "discovering" things, consider reading the documentation.

Comment: @JimBalter You're right, but the language spec is hundreds of pages long. Many of us primarily learn the base language with books/tutorials then read portions of the original documentation as a supplement. Discovering, except for those that know everything, is required part of learning.

Comment: One should at least read through K&R or something equivalent ... any decent C textbook will mention that sizeof is a keyword, not a function, and that it can be followed by either an expression or a parenthesized type. Likewise will be mentioned that return is followed by an expression that does not need to be parenthesized.  There are many things that can be discovered, but the basic syntax rules should not be ... they should be learned. BTW, your question is strange ... the type after `sizeof` is obviously not a type cast, since it has no expression to be cast.

Comment: The "duplicate" isn't one ... it has nothing to do with the OP's question. The OP already knows and stated that the parentheses are needed for the type and not for the expression.

Comment: "somehow being used by sizeof" -- sizeof is not an agent; the compiler is. The compiler of course knows or can calculate the size of any type at compile time (except for VLAs). `sizeof (type)` is just *syntax* that tells the compiler that the size of the type is wanted at that point.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`()` is used with `sizeof` operator if the operand is a *data type*.

#### C11: 6.5.3.4 (p2):

> The `sizeof` operator yields the size (in bytes) of its operand, which may be an
> expression or **the parenthesized name of a type**. The size is determined from the type of the operand.

Comment: Do the parentheses really tell the compiler that what's inside is a type? Couldn't an expression be in parentheses as well?

Comment: @FredLarson; Hmmm..Valid point!. Edited the answer.