# Use of sizeof without parenthesis

Tags: c++, c, sizeof

I have seen use of size of operator without parenthesis.

For example

```
int x,y;
y = sizeof x;
```

1. what is the difference between `sizeof(x)` and `sizeof x`?
2. And why `sizeof int` does not work like `sizeof(int)`?

Comment: See [What does sizeof without () do?](http://stackoverflow.com/q/18898736/1708801)

Comment: @ShafikYaghmour Thank you for the information

Comment: @ShafikYaghmour I don't think anyone would have blamed you for closing that yourself.

Comment: Ahh.. self answer, eh? But the issue is, this is not a better version of the dupe, tough luck, I'd say. :)

Comment: Ditto @BaummitAugen. (I was actually surprised to see the question was open, after SY posted the dupe. :) )

Comment: Found answer from another link. Just thought it could be useful for others :)

Answer (score 0):

Since `sizeof` is a unary operator, it can be used before any variable or constant just like the unary operator '-' and typecast operator. So the parenthesis is not necessary if it is used with a variable or constant.

Just like `-1` and `-(1)` work.

But if it is used with a data type, missing the parenthesis will give compiler error.