# Create a copy of the values inside of an array from the array itself in C

Tags: c, arrays

I have an array with it the first `x_size*y_size` values filled, and now I need to duplicate them `DATA_JUMP` times in the same array in later memory.

```
for(int i=1; i < DATA_JUMP; i++)
 for(int k = 0; k < x_size*y_size; k++)
  orig_depth[k + i*x_size*y_size] = orig_depth[k];
```

This works like I want it to, however this may slow down on large datasets. I wonder if there is a trick to do this with a little pointer arithmetic.

Comment: `memcpy(orig_depth + i*x_size*y_size, orig_depth, x_size*y_size * sizeof *orig_depth);` instead of the inner loop.

Comment: Thank you, works like a charm - do you want to give it as an answer so I can accept it?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use

```
memcpy(orig_depth + i*x_size*y_size, orig_depth, x_size*y_size * sizeof *orig_depth);
```

instead of the inner loop. You have to be sure that `i*x_size*y_size` is not `0`, because in this case the pointer would overlap.

`sizeof *orig_depth` is the size of 1 element of the array, while `sizeof orig_depth` is the size of the whole array.
for `int orig_depth[100];` `sizeof *orig_depth` is `sizeof(int)` and `sizeof orig_depth` is `100 * sizeof(int)`.

The advantage of `sizeof *orig_depth` against `sizeof(int)` is, that you can change the type without the requirement of changing every `sizeof`. The best pratice name for this is: Single source of Truth https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Single_source_of_truth

Comment: One question what does sizeof *orig_depth means in comparison to sizeof(orig_depth) ? Coud you please elaborate

Comment: There are `sizeof unary-expression` and `sizeof ( type-name )`, read about it here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18898736/what-does-sizeof-without-do