# Why does sizeof(!0) print 1 instead of 4?

Tags: c++, c++11, sizeof

```
#include <iostream>

int main()
{
    std::cout<<sizeof(0);
    return 0;
}
```

Here, `sizeof(0)` is `4` in C++ because `0` is an integer rvalue.

But, If I write like this:

```
std::cout<<sizeof(!0);
```

here, `sizeof(!0)` is `1`. But, `!0` means it print `1`, which is also, `int` type.

then, Why does `sizeof(!0)` print `1` instead of `4`? What am I miss here?

Comment: `!0` is a `bool`

Comment: @SidS it means, it is implicitly converted int to bool type.

Comment: @SidS But, sizeof does not evaluate the expression

Comment: @M.SChaudhari yes, it receives already the result of the evaluation

Comment: @M.SChaudhari  - `sizeof` does not evaluate the expression.   It works out the size of the type that would hold the result of the expression.

Comment: Okey. Thanks to all for clear my doubt.

Comment: Also note that `sizeof(int)` does not have to be `4`, nor does `sizeof(bool) = 1`. But it is enough for identification of this question.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

The [logical negation](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/operator_logical) operator:

```
! rhs
```

> **If the operand is not bool, it is converted to bool** using contextual conversion to bool: it is only well-formed if the declaration bool t(arg) is well-formed, for some invented temporary t.
>
> The result is a bool prvalue.

And `sizeof (bool)` *which is implementation defined* is 1 in your implementation.

Comment: Note you are missing a key point which is we are using [sizeof w/ an expression not a type](https://stackoverflow.com/a/18898832/1708801)

Comment: `bool operator!(int);` So bool has a size of 1.

Answer (score 7):

`!0` is a `bool`.

`sizeof(bool)` depends on implementation.

Comment: Why anybody say `!` is the short for `operator!()` is it that implicit?

Answer (score 3):

By prepending the integer value with `!`, you convert it to a boolean - which can be represented using a single byte.

Comment: you most probably mean a single *byte*. If you want to get a single bit per boolean, you would need some kind of bitfield.

Comment: <joke>@Grzegorz Piwowarek So you expect it to be $\frac{1}{8}$?</joke>

Comment: Byte :) also, int is more than 4 bits!

Answer (score 1):

When we write `0` it is an integer, but when we write `!0`, it implicitly convert the integer to boolean.
`!` operator turns any integer into boolean, you can try by writing `!1`, `!2`....these all give size of `1` byte.
if you wanna know the size of `!0` as an int, you can typecast it as

```
sizeof(int(!0));
```