# Why sizeof 1+1 is 5?

Tags: c, sizeof

I am on gcc version 10.3.0 for Ubuntu.
I am learning how `sizeof expression` means in C.
I tried:

```c
int k = 1;
sizeof k+k;
```

Which returns 5, the same goes to `sizeof 1+1`, which differs from `sizeof(int)`(4).

Shouldn't this `sizeof` operation evaluates to `sizeof(int)`, which evaluates to a 4? Does this mean that during an addition, the int grows to a 5-byte long data structure?

Comment: `sizeof k+k` = `sizeof(k)+k` = `4 + 1` = `5`; `sizeof k+k` is different to `sizeof(k+k)`

Comment: I prefer positioning the parenthesis like this: `(sizeof k) + k` ... *some people insist on using parenthesis for the `sizeof` operand... `(sizeof (k)) + k`*

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Just like multiplication/division have a higher precedence (evaluation priority) than addition/subtraction in an algebra expression, C/C++ has operator precedence as well.

`sizeof` is just another operator.  And its operator precedence is 2 levels above addition/subtraction operators.

So it evaluates `sizeof k + k` the same as `(sizeof k) + k` instead of `sizeof(k+k)`

[image]

Comment: Precedence determines expression structure, not evaluation priority. A function call has higher precedence than `&&`, but `0 && f()` does not prioritize calling `f` over evaluating `&&`.

Answer (score 2):

It basically does `sizeof(k) + k` -> 4 + 1 = 5. See also [what-does-sizeof-without-do](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18898736/what-does-sizeof-without-do).